# Count the required arguments of a method

Tags: php

Is it posible to count how many arguments are required from outside this class ?

```
Class a{
    Public function bbb ($A, $b, $c){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use class [ReflectionMethod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php)

```
class a { 
  function bbb ($A, $b, $c){
  }
}

$func_reflection = new ReflectionMethod('a','bbb');
echo $num_of_params = $func_reflection->getNumberOfParameters(); // 3
```

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!